# Incorrect code is being called in 'if/elif/else' statement

Tags: python, boolean

I'm making an interest calculator that does compound and simple interest. However, the if statement always runs the simple interest script regardless of input.

I have tried changing variables to strings, integers, and floats. I have tried changing variable names, I have tried removing the first block of code entirely. What the heck is wrong with it???

```py
start = input("simple or compound: ")

if start == "simple" or "Simple":
    a = float(input('Starting balance: '))
    b = float(input('Rate: '))
    c = int(input('Years: '))

    final = int(a+((a*b*c)/100))
    print(final)
elif start == "compound" or "Compound":
    d = float(input('Starting balance: '))
    e = float(input('Rate: '))
    f = int(input('Years: '))

    final2 = int(d*(1+(e/100))**f)
    print(final2)
else:
    d = float(input('Starting balance: '))
    e = float(input('Rate: '))
    f = int(input('Years: '))

    final3 = int(d*(1+(e/100))**f)
    print(final3)
```

If I input Starting balance as 5000, rate as 5, and years as six into simple it gives 6500. But the same result occurs when I call compound.

Comment: First statement will always be true since evaluating the boolean condition of a string, i.e.`bool('hello')` is always True. What you need is `if start == 'simple' or start == 'Simple'`. Or you can just convert the string to lower case `if start.lower() == 'simple'`. And of course do the same for the `elif`.

Comment: Could also use `if start in ('simple','Simple'):`

Answer (score 0):

This expression is not correct:

`start == "simple" or "Simple"`

should be

`start == "simple" or start "Simple"`

code below worked:

```py
start = input("simple or compound: ")

if start == "simple" or start == "Simple":
    # print("simple")
    a = float(input('Starting balance: '))
    b = float(input('Rate: '))
    c = int(input('Years: '))

    final = int(a+((a*b*c)/100))
    print(final)
elif start == "compound" or start == "Compound":
    # print("compound")
    d = float(input('Starting balance: '))
    e = float(input('Rate: '))
    f = int(input('Years: '))

    final2 = int(d*(1+(e/100))**f)
    print(final2)
else:
    # print("unknown")
    d = float(input('Starting balance: '))
    e = float(input('Rate: '))
    f = int(input('Years: '))

    final3 = int(d*(1+(e/100))**f)
    print(final3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of operator precedence

```
if start == "simple" or "Simple"
```

is evaluated as

```
if (start == "simple") or "Simple"
```

The `(...)` part is True if the user entered "simple", but the "Simple" part is always True.